# SQL group table by "leading rows" without pl/sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I have this table (short example) with two columns

```
1 a
2 a
3 a3
4 a
5 a
6 a6
7 a
8 a8
9 a
```

and I would like to group/partition them into groups separated by those leading "a", ideally to add another column like this, so I can address those groups easily.

```
1 a  0
2 a  0
3 a3 3
4 a  3
5 a  3
6 a6 6
7 a  6
8 a8 8
9 a  8
```

problem is that setup of the table is dynamic so I can't use staticly lag or lead functions, any ideas how to do this without pl/sql in postgres version 9.5

Comment: Since PL/SQL is the *Oracle* procedural language, you'll find it surprisingly simple to keep it out of your Postgres query. You meant PL/pgSQL?

Comment: yes I ment PL/pgSQL, I am just so used to pl/sql when addressing procedural language for sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting rows containing `a` to a specific value and all the other rows to a different value. Then use a cumulative sum to get the desired number for the rows. The group number is set to the next number when a new value in the val column is encountered and all the proceeding rows with `a` will have the same group number as the one before and this continues.

I assume that you would need a distinct number for each group and the number doesn't matter.

```
select id, val, sum(ex) over(order by id) cm_sum
from (select t.*
      ,case when val = 'a' then 0 else 1 end ex
      from t) x
```

The result for the query above with the data in question, would be

```
id  val cm_sum
--------------
1   a   0
2   a   0
3   a3  1
4   a   1
5   a   1
6   a6  2
7   a   2
8   a8  3
9   a   3
```

Comment: Thanks, your is really simple ........ and actually there is no need for that sub query and that case can be put directly into window function sum

Comment: @Baker: Simple. And incorrect. The question didn't ask for a serial number, but for the actual string (or number) contained in the column.

Comment: Yes  @Erwin Brandstetter, you are right, your answer is 100% correct answer to my question by it's definition, ... however this solution serve the purpose I needed, because it's offering a way to separate those groups

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the leading part is a *single character*. Hence the expression `right(data, -1)` works to extract the group name. Adapt to your actual prefix.

The solution uses two [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), which can't be nested. So we need a subquery or a CTE.

```sql
SELECT id, data
     , COALESCE(first_value(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_nr ORDER BY id), '0') AS grp
FROM (
   SELECT *, NULLIF(right(data, -1), '') AS grp
        , count(NULLIF(right(data, -1), '')) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp_nr
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub;
```

Produces your desired result exactly.

`NULLIF(right(data, -1), '')` to get the effective group name or `NULL` if none.

`count()` only counts non-null values, so we get a higher count for every new group in the subquery.

In the outer query, we take the first `grp` value per `grp_nr` as group name and default to '0' with `COALESCE` for the first group without name (which has a `NULL` as group name so far).

We could use `min()` or `max()` as outer window function as well, since there is only *one* non-null value per partition anyway. `first_value()` is probably cheapest since the rows are sorted already.

Note the group name `grp` is data type `text`. You may want to cast to integer, if those are clean (and reliably) integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With the given data, you can use a cumulative max:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(max(substr(col2, 2)) over (order by col1), 0)
```

If you don't strictly want the maximum, then it gets a bit more difficult.  The ANSI solution is to use the `IGNORE NULL`s option on `LAG()`.  However, Postgres does not (yet) support that.  An alternative is:

```
select . . ., coalesce(substr(reft.col2, 2), 0)
from (select . . .,
             max(case when col2 like 'a_%' then col1 end) over (order by col1) as ref_col1
      from t
     ) tt join
     t reft
     on tt.ref_col1 = reft.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
 with mytable as (select split_part(t,' ',1)::integer id,split_part(t,' ',2) myvalue 
       from (select unnest(string_to_array($$1 a;2 a;3 a3;4 a;5 a;6 a6;7 a;8 a8;9 a$$,
    ';'))t) a)

  select id,myvalue,myresult from mytable join (
     select COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(myvalue,2),''),'0') myresult,idmin id_down
            ,COALESCE(lead(idmin) over (order by myvalue),999999999999) id_up 
   from (
     select myvalue,min(id) idmin from mytable group by 1
    ) a) b 
  on id between id_down and id_up-1
```