# How to do forward fill as a PL/PGSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions

I am trying to create a pl/pgsql equivalent to the pandas 'ffill' function. The function should forward fill null values. In the example I can do a forward fill but I get errors when I try to create a function from my procedure. The function seems to reflect exactly the procedure but I get a syntax error at the portion `... as $1`.

Why? What should I be reading to clarify?

```
-- Forward fill experiment
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
create temporary table example(id int, str text, val integer);
insert into example values
(1, 'a', null),
(1, null, 1),
(2, 'b', 2),
(2,null ,null );

select * from example

select (case
            when str is null
            then lag(str,1) over (order by id)
            else str
            end) as str,
            (case
            when val is null
            then lag(val,1) over (order by id)
            else val
            end) as val
from example

-- Forward fill function
create or replace function ffill(text, text, text) -- takes column to fill, the table, and the ordering column 
returns text as $$
    begin
        select (case
            when $1 is null
            then lag($1 ,1) over (order by $3)
            else $1
            end) as $1
        from $2;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Update 1**:   I did some additional experimenting taking a different approach.  The code is below.  It uses the same example table as above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GapFillInternal( 
    s anyelement, 
    v anyelement) RETURNS anyelement AS 
$$
declare 
    temp alias for $0 ;
begin
    RAISE NOTICE 's= %, v= %', s, v;
    if v is null and s notnull then
        temp := s;
    elsif s is null and v notnull then
        temp := v;
    elsif s notnull and v notnull then 
        temp := v;
    else
        temp := null;
    end if;
    RAISE NOTICE 'temp= %', temp;
    return temp;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL; 

CREATE AGGREGATE GapFill(anyelement) ( 
  SFUNC=GapFillInternal, 
  STYPE=anyelement 
);

select id, str, val, GapFill(val) OVER (ORDER by id) as valx
from example;
```

The resulting table is this:

[image]

I don't understand where the '1' in the first row of `valx` column comes from. From the `raise notice` output it should be `Null` and that seems a correct expectation from the [`CREATE AGGREGATE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createaggregate.html).

[image]

Comment: You probably want `OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY some_other_keyfield)`

Comment: @wildplasser in the example, as in my real application, there's no other key field.  Ideally I want to forward fill on any and all the columns.  For example, if I had just one column I would want to able to forward fill on that.  Ideally the order would be over the row number.

Comment: @wildplasser based on your comment it seemed I needed another column that reflected absolute row order as I indicated in my reply.  My solution then was to alter the table by adding a 'row_number' column using 'serial'.  That made things work but doesn't explain the challenge I encountered in my update.

Comment: For data, we very much prefer *text* over images. And please remember to declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Correct call

Seems like your displayed query is incorrect, and the test case is just too reduced to show it.

Assuming you want to "forward fill" **partitioned by `id`**, you'll have to say so:

```sql
SELECT row_num, id
     , str, gap_fill(str) OVER w AS strx
     , val, gap_fill(val) OVER w AS valx
FROM   example
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_num);  -- !
```

The `WINDOW` clause is just a syntactical convenience to avoid spelling out the same window frame repeatedly. The important part is the added `PARTITION` clause.

#### Simpler function

Much simpler, actually:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gap_fill_internal(s anyelement, v anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN COALESCE(v, s);  -- that's all!
END
$func$;

CREATE AGGREGATE gap_fill(anyelement) ( 
  SFUNC = gap_fill_internal, 
  STYPE = anyelement 
);
```

Slightly faster in a quick test.

#### Standard SQL

Without custom function:

```sql
SELECT row_num, id
     , str, first_value(str) OVER (PARTITION BY id, ct_str ORDER BY row_num) AS strx
     , val, first_value(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id, ct_val ORDER BY row_num) AS valx
FROM (     
   SELECT *, count(str) OVER w AS ct_str, count(val) OVER w AS ct_val
   FROM   example
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_num)
   ) sub;
```

The query becomes more complex with a subquery. Performance is similar. Slightly slower in a quick test.

More explanation in these related answers:

- [Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186244/3684)
- [Retrieve last known value for each column of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246242/retrieve-last-known-value-for-each-column-of-a-row/20253371#20253371)
- [SQL group table by "leading rows" without pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104326/sql-group-table-by-leading-rows-without-pl-sql/38105466#38105466)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f407a2f3c7c611ec8c556b31a04aff66)* - showing all with extended test case

Comment: I have followed up this question with an attempt to generalize it.  Basically I want to apply this function to any table without having to craft the 'select ...'  ie. the function would extract the column names and run gap_fill on the columns.  My question and attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71056951/applying-a-function-to-all-columns-in-a-postgresql-table